# Rails - Can I run rake assets:precompile on production server, while the production app is still running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, asset-pipeline, web-deployment, pre-compilation

Sorry if this question sounds basic. But I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere on the web...

I'm currently running my Rails app on a Ubuntu server. Until now I've always shut down the production app before I pull the changes, run `rake assets:clean assets:precompile`, and only boot up the Rails app again once the process is finished.

I'm not sure whether the shutting down of app is necessary(i.e. if I don't do it, my app will behave erratically). It induces about 5 minutes of down time.

If that's a must, then maybe I should try to do local precompilation/more advanced deployment procedure, in order to reduce downtime? (Tried local compilation according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation, but then after deleting original `public/assets` and pulling locally precompiled `public/assets` from the repo, the production server was having rack timeout all the time and won't render anything.)

Answer (score 3):

YES you run `rake assets:precompile` Rails looks through your `assets` folder and copies over everything that is not Javascript or CSS into `public/assets`. It then creates `application.js` by reading `app\assets\javascripts\application.js`, and `application.css` by reading `app\assets\stylesheets\application.css`, loading up all the "require" files it finds in there.
**So yes..you can do it** ..but if you ran `rake assets:clean`..and then precompile...then `public/assets` will be updated with new compiled assets.

***Dont forget to restart the server*** :)